# Как добавить имя участника в эмбед сообщение после того, как он нажмёт на реакцию?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

пишу дискорд бота для сбора/поиска игроков(по типу lfg). Нужно чтобы бот, после того как участник нажмёт на реакцию (например на плюсик или галочку) добавил его имя в текст embed сообщения. Должно выглядеть примерно так: [image: Пример]

При последующем нажатии на эту же реакцию этим же участником нужно убрать текст. Если кто-то другой нажмёт на реакцию, то он тоже появится, но уже ниже. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как такое реализовать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Через ивент "on_raw_reaction_add"

Comment: спасибо, попробую